# How to allow browsers to cache Craft's admin static files?

Tags: cache, admin

I notice that the Craft admin pages append random query parameters to their static files, i.e. `jquery-2.2.1.min.js?x=AKVKl03So`:

[image: example network data from admin, showing query parameters]

This prevents those static files being cached in browsers, which can make the admin views unreliable in less-than-optimal network conditions.

I see the logic to make this happen is in Craft's [`app/helpers/UrlHelper.php`](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/Craft-Release/blob/768ba7b2afd471771f6f449b28308c7e1fe8fefd/app/helpers/UrlHelper.php#L254-L307)

Is there a sane way to deactivate that behavior, and allow browsers to cache Craft's static files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's a great idea to disable this cache busting; they put it in there for a reason.  However, if you really need/want to do it, instead of modifying Craft, I'd just configure Apache/Nginx to discard the query string for paths that match `/admin/resources/`

https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteQueryString

Comment: Thanks! That would do the job, but I agree that it's probably not a great idea - future changes to static files won't appear in users' browsers because of the caching.

What I'd really love is a way to trigger that [`$dateParam` logic](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/Craft-Release/blob/768ba7b2afd471771f6f449b28308c7e1fe8fefd/app/helpers/UrlHelper.php#L275-L288) for all the static files, so that they deterministic `?d=` query parameters instead of random `?x=` query parameters, thus getting both browser-side caching and also graceful cache invalidation when updates happen.

Comment: If you're going through the trouble of dropping the query string, theoretically you could setup how far out the cache should be on the admin side as well, say an hour or 2 depending on how long your authors are in the site for.